# nginx installation failed in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, nginx

When trying to install `nginx`in Debian 9/stretch with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-full
```

The installation failed with the errors:

```
Setting up nginx-full (1.10.2-2) ...
[FAIL] Starting nginx: nginx failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error shows `nginx` is not able to start. Thus as the post-install scripts on Stretch are dependent on it starting for the installation to be successful, it shows that error.

Upon trying to boot it on further debug of the problem, it shows a more clear error:

```
#nginx
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
```

What it happens here, is that this server has IPv6 disabled, and the installation assumes this is a dual stack machine.

To correct this problem, edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and comment:

```
#listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

Now try to install it again, and it should work.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-full
```

In alternative, as @Stephen Kitt pointed out:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

Comment: After the first (failed) installation of `nginx-full`, once the configuration file is corrected it should also be possible to complete the installation by running `dpkg --configure --pending`, without re-installing the package.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah, it makes sense, thanks